# How to change firefox's about:home page with theme?

Tags: firefox, themes

I want to create a theme, and I also need to customize about:home page. None of the themes that I've downloaded from library, didn't change about:home page. I know how to change about:home manually, but I need to change it with the theme. Is it possible?

P.S. Themes in the library have screenshots with different about:home pages. But my firefox 16.0.2 doesnt change about:home page. Mb this feature was removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the solution but you might get some clues by following steps:

- Run about:config on firefox
- Click on "I'll be careful, I promise"
- You'll get configuration of your browser, simply type the config name on search box

You might get any clue how to do your task.